# How to specify an array in the Where clause using Moodle DB API Call?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, moodle

I want to filter data based on an array, similar to "in" keyword in a query:

```
SELECT count(*) as number_of_records, 
       count(CASE WHEN result = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 END) as successful_builds_no,
       min(CASE WHEN result = 'FAILURE' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as is_success,
       min(duration) as best_duration,
       max(build_date) as build_date     
FROM   mdl_selenium_results
WHERE build_date in ('2014-03-13', '2014-03-12')
GROUP BY build_date
```

How to achieve that using Moodle DB api??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating an SQL query to use within Moodle, you could just use the IN keyword, exactly as you have done in the example.

Alternatively, to make it a bit more cross-DB compatible, and to make your queries run a bit faster when there is only one item in the list, you can write:

```
list($dsql, $dparam) = $DB->get_in_or_equal(array('2014-03-13', '2014-03-12'), SQL_PARAMS_NAMED);

$sql = "SELECT count(*) as number_of_records, 
       count(CASE WHEN result = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 END) as successful_builds_no,
       min(CASE WHEN result = 'FAILURE' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as is_success,
       min(duration) as best_duration,
       max(build_date) as build_date     
FROM   {selenium_results}
WHERE build_date $dsql
GROUP BY build_date";

$result = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, $dparams);
```

OR, if you just want to get all the matching records from the given table (and then worry about doing the calculations in PHP), you could write:

```
$result = $DB->get_records_list('selenium_results', 'build_date', array('2014-03-13', '2014-03-12'));
```

(I've not run any of the code above, so apologies for any typos)